# Cordova / Phonegap plugins not working in sub folders

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a complex Cordova / Phonegap application that forces me **not** to have all my application load under a Single Page Application structure.

I have pages that **download to local file system** and are **navigated to**. In these pages plugins arent accessible for example `window.plugins == undefined`

I know that you need to reference `cordova.js` which intern references `cordova_plugins.js` 
I tried **copying these two files** over to the sub folder and reference them. but still no go... i assume there a path violation occurring

- `[installed app]/ index.html`
- `[installed app]/ cordova.js`
- `[installed app]/ cordova_plugins.js`

then in the downloaded folder

- `[downloadDirectory.toURL()]/other.html`
- `[downloadDirectory.toURL()]/ cordova.js (copied)`
- `[downloadDirectory.toURL()]/ cordova_plugins.js (copied)`

Anyone know how i can get around this issue?

Comment: I dont see how this could matter because to my knowledge cordova pretty much is a webview and no matter where you navigate to you're still within the same webview and codova.js talks to the parent webview.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging in for a while, here is what I found none of the following are reliable:
`window.plugin`
`window.plugins`
`cordova.plugin`
`cordova.plugins`

The may sometimes work because of something influential in the context. You should call the plugin from its namespace ie `device.XXX` not `window.plugins.device`
or `navigator.splashscreen` not `window.plugins.splashscreen`